# SQL segment values of array into pseudo key, value when values change

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I have a SQL array column that consists of 24 values, which is hours of the day (12am - 11pm).

The values follow similar trends to the following: `[1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,4,1,1,1,3,4,4,1,1,0]`
The current order must be maintained as it's showing the timeline of the day.

I am attempting to create a column that would segment that array into start index - end index: value breakouts while the values of the array stay the same. For example `{1 - 6: 1, 7 - 8: 3, 9 - 12: 2, 13: 3, 14: 2, 15: 4, 16 - 18: 1, 19: 3, 20 - 21: 4, 22 - 23: 1, 24: 0}`

I am running this through Presto/Trino, but can also use hive if thats a better solution. I have tried different functionality from this page https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html combined with if/case statements, but falling flat. I've looked into while looping the data, but am not too familiar with the  functionality and how it interacts with the column or even how to combine it with the current code.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for what I needed:

```
with arr as (
select array [2,4,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,4,4,2,1,1] as arr
)
, expl as (
select t.val, t.n from arr
cross join unnest(arr) with ordinality as t (val, n)
)
, expl1 as (
select val, n, lead(val) over (order by n) as next_val
from expl
)
, expl2 as (
select val, n
from expl1
where val <> next_val
)
, expl3 as (
select val, case when lag(n) over (order by n) is null then 1 else lag(n) over (order by n) + 1 end as min_time
, case when lead(n) over (order by n) is null then 24 else n end as max_time
from expl2
)
, expl4 as (
select cast(min_time as varchar(2)) || ' - ' || cast(max_time as varchar(2)) || ': ' || cast(val as varchar(2)) as Breakout
from expl3
)
select array_agg(breakout)
from expl4
;
```